# How to write a query to retrieve latest record only in one to many relationship?

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables: `tableA` and `tableB`. One row in `tableA` has many records in `tableB`.

How do I write a select query to join both tables and return only the latest record from `tableB` when joining.

Ex:
TableA

```
ID   NAME
--
ABC  JOHN
```

TableB

```
ID   Role LastUpdateDate
--
ABC  M    07/07/15
ABC  C    03/04/14
ABC  S    03/04/17
```

I want to retrieve ABC, JOHN, S, 03/04/17

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this.

```
select tableB.ID,tableB.Role, Max(tableB.LastUpdateDate)
from tableA inner join tableB
on tableA.ID = tableB.ID
group by tableB.ID,tableB.Role;
```